# Getting common columns names in R from two data frames

Tags: r

I have two vectors containing strings:

```
names_1 <- c("A", "B", "C", "D")
names_2 <- c("C", "D", "E")
```

How do I know which strings from names_1 exist in names_2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
which(names_1 %in% names_2)
```

This will return the index of selected strings.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to to get a logical vector, you could use:

```
is.element(names_1, names_2)
```

If you want to get the elements, which are the same, you could use:

```
intersect(names_1, names_2)
```